# expand numpy array in n dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to 'expand' an array (generate a new array with proportionally more elements in all dimensions). I have an array with known numbers (let's call it `X`) and I want to make it `j` times bigger (in each dimension).

So far I generated a new array of zeros with more elements, then I used broadcasting to insert the original numbers in the new array (at fixed intervals).

Finally, I used `linspace` to fill the gaps, but this part is actually not directly relevant to the question.

The code I used (for n=3) is:

```
import numpy as np
new_shape = (np.array(X.shape) - 1 ) * ratio + 1
new_array = np.zeros(shape=new_shape)
new_array[::ratio,::ratio,::ratio] = X
```

My problem is that this is not general, I would have to modify the third line based on `ndim`. Is there a way to use such broadcasting for any number of dimensions in my array?

Edit: to be more precise, the third line would have to be:

```
new_array[::ratio,::ratio] = X
```

if ndim=2
or

```
new_array[::ratio,::ratio,::ratio,::ratio] = X
```

if ndim=4

etc. etc. I want to avoid having to write code for each case of ndim

p.s. If there is a better tool to do the entire process (such as 'inner-padding' that I am not aware of, I will be happy to learn about it).

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `slice` notation -

```
slicer = tuple(slice(None,None,ratio) for i in range(X.ndim))
new_array[slicer] = X
```

Answer (score 3):

`array = array[..., np.newaxis]` will add another dimension

[This article might help](https://www.python-course.eu/numpy_changing_dimensions.php)

Answer (score 2):

Build the slicing tuple manually. `::ratio` is equivalent to `slice(None, None, ratio)`:

```
new_array[(slice(None, None, ratio),)*new_array.ndim] = ...
```